# Occasionally crash with _nano_malloc_check_clear

Tags: ios, memory, crash, release

The crash is SIGABRT, which is not "selector not found". May be over release. But the crash only occurs on arm64 devices and stacks are not the same.

I also find _nano_malloc_check_clear source, http://opensource.apple.com/source/libmalloc/libmalloc-53.1.1/src/nano_malloc.c

Another suspending crash related with _nano_malloc_check_clear is,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30802134/app-crashes-entering-foreground-with-uistatusbar

Such kind of crashes never happened in previous versions or 32bit devices. I use 10 threads simultaneously with infinite loop on iPhone6 plus to reproduce, but failed.

Log 1:

```
Exception Type:  SIGABRT
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x195217270
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x0000000195217270 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x000000019518eb18 abort + 112
2   libsystem_malloc.dylib              0x00000001952523e4 _nano_malloc_check_clear + 0
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib              0x00000001952512f8 nano_free + 192
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000184225444 CFRelease + 1064
5   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001842cdcc8 __CFBinaryPlistCreateObjectFiltered + 2480
6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001842ceb10 __CFBinaryPlistCreateObjectFiltered + 6136
7   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001842cf06c __CFTryParseBinaryPlist + 204
8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000184222f04 _CFPropertyListCreateWithData + 124
9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018424f2fc CFPropertyListCreateWithData + 104
10  Foundation                          0x000000018514f1d8 +[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:options:format:error:] + 112
11  AlipayWallet                        0x00000001012e2160 decodeObjectFromData + 148
```

Log 2:

```
Thread 36 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x0000000197a13270 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x000000019798ab18 abort + 112
2   libsystem_malloc.dylib              0x0000000197a4e3e4 _nano_malloc_check_clear + 0
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib              0x0000000197a4d2f8 nano_free + 192
4   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x000000019765689c 0x1975a8000 + 714908
5   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x000000019761606c 0x1975a8000 + 450668
6   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x0000000197670fc8 0x1975a8000 + 823240
7   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x00000001975c9f90 0x1975a8000 + 139152
8   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x00000001975f0cf0 0x1975a8000 + 298224
9   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x00000001975e3368 sqlite3_step + 528
10  AlipayWallet                        0x00000001012fe038 -[FMDatabase executeUpdate:error:withArgumentsInArray:orDictionary:orVAList:] + 1756
11  AlipayWallet                        0x00000001012fe41c -[FMDatabase executeUpdate:withArgumentsInArray:] + 76
```

Log 3:

```
Thread 36 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x0000000195f97270 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x0000000195f0eb18 abort + 112
2   libsystem_malloc.dylib              0x0000000195fd23e4 _nano_malloc_check_clear + 0
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib              0x0000000195fd12f8 nano_free + 192
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000183fb4d40 __CFArrayReleaseValues + 492
5   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000183f11394 CFRelease + 328
6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000183fb9948 __CFBinaryPlistWriteOrPresize + 504
7   Foundation                          0x0000000184eb2668 -[NSKeyedArchiver finishEncoding] + 604
8   Foundation                          0x0000000184eb8370 +[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:] + 212
```

Comment: When there's a `SIGABRT`, there's always something logged to the console.  Do you know what was logged, or was this on a user's device?

Comment: I cannot reproduce with Xcode debugging. These crash reports are uploaded from user devices.